# Setting up nginx conf for Django-Rest-Framework backend + Vuejs frontend

Tags: nginx, django, google-cloud-platform

I'm running on instance on Google Cloud. I have an app which uses DRF for the api (using gunicorn), and Vuejs on the frontend. I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on requests made from the browser and trying to figure out how to get this setup correctly. Here's my current nginx conf file:

```
upstream django-api {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "SERVER_IP";
    location / {
        alias /path/to/website/;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /dist/ {
        alias /path/to/js/files;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://django-api;
    }

    location /rest-auth/ {
        proxy-pass http://django-api;
    }
}
```

In the Vue app I am using axios to make http calls and I am using SERVER_IP:8000 as the base url/port. Again the kind of error I'm seeing in the browser:

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://XX.XXX.XXX.xx:8000/api/rest/url/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: What do the nginx log files show?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make an HTTP connection to port 8000 on the server, but your web server has only port 80 open to outside world.

You need to make your requests to port 80 in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but now I'm just getting 404 Not Found errors.